# How to use ditto on OS X to work like cp -a on Linux

Tags: macos

I'm a Linux guy and I'm used to copying directory trees with `cp -a`. OS X doesn't have `-a` option on `cp`... but it does have the `ditto` command. I'm reading the man on `ditto` now, but is there anything I should specifically be looking out for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the **cp** man page **cp -a** is the same as **cp -dpR** which is

```
-p = preserve mode,ownership,timestamps
-R = recursive
-d = no dereference and preserve links
```

The OS X equivalent would be

**cp -pPR**

```
-p = preserve
-R = recursive
-P = no symbolic links are followed -- can be added but this is the default behavior
```

The only thing missing is **-d** which I think is the default behavior but I'm not positive.

I've never messed with **ditto**

Edit -- @SoloBold

**-L** follows symbolic links.  **-p** does NOT follow symbolic links.
OS X (10.4 at least) has no **-d** option.

that is a huge difference.

Comment: cp -pPR should do the job, on 10.5 at least.

Comment: sudo ditto -vV -rsrcFork /Users /Volumes/Backups/Users ( which will copy a given directory, including all hidden files and resource forks)

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use `rsync -a` (or whatever `rsync` params are called for). My two reasons are: I already know how to do this, and I need my scripts to be portable across Linux/BSD/Solaris. There are also some filesystems where `rsync` is more efficient than `cp`.

Sorry that's not a direct answer, I have used `ditto` on BSDs but don't have any gotchas for you that aren't in the man page.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ditto, you should be aware that it moves the contents a bit differently from `cp -a` when it comes to folders:

```
ditto foo bar
```

will move the contents of foo into bar (resulting in bar/file1, bar/file2 .. )

```
cp -a foo bar
```

will move foo/ into bar/ (resulting in bar/foo/file1, bar/foo/file2, .. )

Also: OSX cp now support `cp -a`.

Answer (score 1):

From Linux cp(1):

> -a, --archive same as -dpR

which is confusing, since -d appears to be equivalent to -p. Anyway, OSX has -p and -R so you could just use that.

Comment: From the OS X man pages: "Symbolic links are always followed unless the -R flag is set, in which case symbolic links are not followed."  Which is opposite to the way Linux works.

Answer (score 0):

As j04t pointed out that should be `cp -pR`

<strike>On OS X, you would do</strike>

```
cp -dRL src target
```

cp preserves resources in newer version of OS X (was it 10.3 when that happened?)

Hey d is kinda like an upsidedown p, right ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between ditto and cp which is that when source is a directory, cp creates a directory with that name on the destination, but ditto just copies the contents. Beware!